# Makefile clean doesn't rm remove the files I want

Tags: makefile, latex, rm

my Makefile is like the follwing:

```
all:
        pdflatex file.tex
        pdflatex file.tex
        pdflatex file.tex
        bibtex file
        pdflatex file.tex
        pdflatex file.tex

clean:
        rm -rf *.aux *.toc *.log *.out *.bbl *.blg
```

Everything works fine, **but** at the end, *none* of the files with the above extensions get removed.

I don't get any error message, as the end of the output is the following:

```
Output written on file.pdf (175 pages, 35867283 bytes).
Transcript written on file.log.
```

Any guess why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type "make clean" in the command line and it will clean those

Comment: Many thanks! It was quite obvious I'm a complete newbie with Makefile, right? :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing a lot of unnecessary commands, you could compile with

```
 latexmk -c -pdf file
```

`latexmk` will automatically determine which and how many runs of latex, bibtex etc. are necessary and with the `-c` option, all non-essential files will be cleaned up